# Trouble updating the margin property of buttons to animate them

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone-8, margin, transformation

I have a WP8 app where I display buttons on a wheel. When clicked, I want the wheel to turn and bring the clicked button on the top of it.

I'm placing the buttons with their margin property. I figured I'd use a double while loop to move the buttons along the circle degree by degree, like this (trying to simplify it as much as I can) :

```
private void Select(Button selectedButton)
{
    Button[] SelectedButtons = { button1, button2, button3 };
    //Calculates the distance between buttons in degrees
    double buttonDistance = 360 / SelectedButtons.Length;

    double angleDeg;
    double angleRad;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    //While the selected button hasn't reach top position, move the wheel
    while (selectedButton.Margin != new Thickness(<top position of the wheel>)
    {
        //Moves the buttons of a single degree
        while (i < SelectedButtons.Length)
        {
            //Calculates the position of the current button in the array in degrees and converts it in radians
            angleDeg = j + 90 + i * buttonDistance;
            angleRad = Math.PI * angleDeg / 180;

            //Button positioning
            SelectedButtons[i].Margin = new Thickness(<calculation of the margins with the given angles>);
            i++;
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

However, and even with the Sleep() function, the buttons' positions only update once the loop is over, and don't animate like I want them too.

I tried to use UpdateLayout() in the loop, both on the ContentPanel and on the Buttons themselves, I tried InvalidateArrange() and InvalidateMeasure(), or even adding a canvas in, but nothing does it : the buttons only update when the whiles are over, never before.

Can you guys please help me on this ?

Comment: This is a really classic case of updating the UI elements quickly from the GUI thread and expecting it to redraw in real time. If you're doing work in the main thread, you aren't updating the GUI. Here's an example of a similar problem I posted a solution to a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667053/appendtext-on-text-box-only-shown-in-the-end-all-together-in-wpf/11670132#11670132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update, for anyone who could stumble upon the same issue :

Indeed, as steveg89 said, you can't update UIElements right from the GUI thread. The link he gave suggests using a background worker, or delegates, to get it to work. Unfortunately, WP8 doesn't allow it either.

The only solution is switching to storyboard animations : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx

Not extremely easy for a absolute beginner, but it works fine when you take the time to understand how these work and their different types (simple animations, keyframe animations, or path animations (however path animations are not supported in Windows Phone. Lost quite a bit of time to it.))